# Two different imports with same path - how to handle?

Tags: java

Currently trying to use the CompoundNBT class from here - https://nekoyue.github.io/ForgeJavaDocs-NG/javadoc/1.16.5/net/minecraft/nbt/CompoundNBT.html

But another package (yarn) has the same class name with the same import statement (net.minecraft.nbt)

I'm wondering how I'd go about specifying that I want the first one because it's currently defaulting to the yarn import, and I can't import any classes from forge that don't exist in yarn.

Comment: You can use Maven shade plugin to rename the dependency, but what is yarn? nodejs yarnpkg or hadoop yarn, or something else?

Comment: Sorry, your question is not clear. What is the "another package"??? You mean another library? What library?

Comment: Add more logs coming from your build tool, with the messages you are receiving, and if you can, show us from how many different places you are taking your dependencies. If I understand well what is happening to you.